# How to calculate sum of integers ArrayList from user input

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sum, integer

Creating a program for a user to input the number of push ups they did in a session, displaying that session's number in one textview while showing the sum of all push up sessions in a second textview.

I tried the code below which seemed to work for a lot of people but I am getting the error "cannot resolve symbol i"

is there an issue with my code, or this method?  Any tips on finding the sum of arraylist items in a date range would be much appreciated too

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ArrayList<Integer> pushuplist = new ArrayList<>();

    EditText PushupEditText = findViewById(R.id.PushupEditText);
    Button AddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);
    AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText PushupEditText = findViewById(R.id.PushupEditText);
            TextView PushupTextView = findViewById(R.id.PushupTextView);
            TextView TotalPushupsText = findViewById(R.id.TotalPushupsText);

            int PushupNum = Integer.parseInt(PushupEditText.getText().toString());
            pushuplist.add(PushupNum);

            PushupTextView.setText(PushupNum+"");

            int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < pushuplist.size(); i++);
            {
                sum += pushuplist.get(i);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon on the end of this line: `for (int i = 0; i < pushuplist.size(); i++);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code below has an extra semicolon after the for loop declaration. Removing that semicolon should do the trick.

```java
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < pushuplist.size(); i++); // remove this semicolon
{
    sum += pushuplist.get(i);
}
```

If you would like to know why this doesn't trigger a compiler error or warning, read on.

When you write a for loop, if no braces are added, the next executable statement will be run in that for loop's iterations.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) System.out.println(i);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.println(i);
```

These are both instances of valid code. In both cases, the print will be triggered 10 times and will print out the value of `i`.

In the case where there is a semicolon after the for loop declaration such as in yours:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < pushuplist.size(); i++);
```

The next executable statement is the semicolon `;`, so nothing is run through all the for loop iterations.

Hopefully that explanation should shed a bit of light on what was going on there.

Good luck with your app!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation! The extra lesson at the end was more helpful than the solution

Answer (score 0):

remove last semicolon:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pushuplist.size(); i++);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mistake in for() 
Use this code instead.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final ArrayList<Integer> pushuplist = new ArrayList<>();

EditText PushupEditText = findViewById(R.id.PushupEditText);
Button AddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);
AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText PushupEditText = findViewById(R.id.PushupEditText);
        TextView PushupTextView = findViewById(R.id.PushupTextView);
        TextView TotalPushupsText = findViewById(R.id.TotalPushupsText);

        int PushupNum = Integer.parseInt(PushupEditText.getText().toString());
        pushuplist.add(PushupNum);

        PushupTextView.setText(PushupNum+"");

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pushuplist.size(); i++)
        {
            sum += pushuplist.get(i);
        }

    }
});
```